# Сайт выполнил переадресацию слишком много раз laravel

Tags: laravel

выскакивает такое при переадресации неавторизованного пользователя

Сайт one.extremje.bget.ru выполнил переадресацию слишком много раз

middleware:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
class AdminAuth
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (!Auth::check()) {
            return redirect()->route('authmanager');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

route:

```
Route::group(['prefix'=>'manager', 'middleware'=>['adminmanager']], function(){
    Route::get('/', 'Admin\DashboardController@dashboard')->name('manager.index');
    Route::get('/login', 'Admin\DashboardController@login')->name('authmanager');
    Route::get('/users', 'Admin\DashboardController@userstat');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Ну все правильно. Вы делаете redirect на route, который входит в группу `'middleware'=>['adminmanager']`. Он пытается снова в него зайти и снова происходит redirect.

Или делайте редирект на route, который не собираетесь проводить через этот middleware, или вынесите `authmanager` из этой группы, чтобы неавторизованный пользователь мог получить к нему доступ.